# Using loop to update a specific part of screen, but how can I do it?

Tags: bash, for-loop

I'm creating a bash script which has 2 parts: a "head" and a "body". This "head" is my script name or part of menu name (like `"SCRIPT: ADD USER", "SCRIPT: LIST USERS"` and etc), and the `"body"` shows messages and menus.

In one specific item of this menu, I'd like to keep the head without any change, and using a loop, update the just the "body".

How can I do it?

```sh
function show_head () {
    echo "BASH Script"
}

show_head
for-loop; do
    ...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
Just using "tput cup X Y", I can keep the header fixed and change the body from the position X and Y, returning to the same position X/Y.